# Updating child association in ActiveModel

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Parent object, and it has a Child object as a has_many association.

i get the first child:

s = Parent.first
str = s.children.first

and change it:

str.remarks = "something"

now, i would expect s.save 
to save the child too, but it doesn't.
i need to explicitly call str.save, which is bad (because its not in a transaction, and its also ugly).

i've tried marking the relations with :autosave=>true (on both sides) but it does nothing.

what's the standard way of solving this?

i'm working in ROR4, ruby 2.0, if it matters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `s` is not aware of the temporary changes you're making to the record, they are stored in `str`.  If you want this to work instead try

`s = Parent.first`

`s.children.first.remarks = "something"`

`s.save`

Comment: related to this: whats the proper way then to iterate over the children and update something on each one? (without calling .save on each child)