# activemodel - updating children of object when saving parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

this is a followup to my question here:
[Updating child association in ActiveModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042116/updating-child-association-in-activemodel/18043988?noredirect=1#18043988)

i'm looking for the standard/correct way to update a number of children records associated with a parent.

lets say i have a parent (connected to a child table with has_many, and :autosave=>true).

```
obj = Parent.first
```

now i iterate over its children, and update them.

```
obj.each.do |child|
    child.remark = "something"
end
```

i would like the children to be saved with the parent, when calling obj.save, but as explained to me in the previous question, the only way to do it is to update it directly, like this:

```
obj.children.first.remark = "something"
```

(or save each child, but this will require an explicit transaction which i believe shouldn't be used here).

what is the correct way to implement this?

thanks!

*edit : 
following the advice given here, i've added this to the model:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base

     has_many :children, :inverse_of => :parent,:autosave=>true

     accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
```

But still,

```
x = Parent.first
c = x.children.first
c.remark = "something"
x.save    # => doesn't update c
```

Comment: so this is `ActiveRecord` or `ActiveModel`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want ActiveRecord [nested_attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

```
class Parent
  include ActiveModel::Model

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
end
```

Update your children and save the parent, you should be done

EDIT: you have to call `parent.children` first:

```
irb(main):001:0> x = Parent.first
  Parent Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "parents".* FROM "parents" ORDER BY "parents"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Parent id: 1, created_at: "2013-08-07 21:21:10", updated_at: "2013-08-07 21:21:10">
irb(main):002:0> x.children
  Child Load (3.0ms)  SELECT "children".* FROM "children" WHERE "children"."parent_id" = ?  [["parent_id", 1]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [ ]>
irb(main):003:0> x.children.first.remark = "foo"
=> "foo"
irb(main):004:0> x.save
   (0.3ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (2.3ms)  UPDATE "children" SET "remark" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "children"."id" = 1  [["remark", "foo"], ["updated_at", Wed, 07 Aug 2013 21:33:04 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.3ms)  commit transaction
=> true
```

Comment: Sure. i'm updating the question.

Comment: calling x.children did the trick. note that accepts_nested_attributes is not really needed here - its enough to put :autosave=>true on the has_many definition

Comment: ok nice, but note on the other hand that as the documentation states: `Note that the :autosave option is automatically enabled on every association that #accepts_nested_attributes_for is used for.` :)

Comment: This is not a valid solution. `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is part of ActiveRecord, not ActiveModel.

Answer (score 1):

You could overwrite the save method but I would not do that. Why not do something like this?

```
def save_with_children
  Child.transaction do
    children.each do |child|
      if child.changed?
        child.save
      end
    end
  end
  save
end
```

This should run 1 query. Probably wouldn't work if you had 10'000'000 records but you didn't mention that.

Comment: This does seem like the only way, but its strange that when adding records with build (and in all other ORMs i've used) you don't need it.

Comment: wrapping the save in a transaction is also what does `nested_attributes_for`